# Use a grep command in python

Tags: python, shellcode

There is a command like the following:

```
for i in $(objdump -d binary |grep "^ " |cut -f2); do echo -n '\x'$i; done;echo
```

How can I use this command in my python code and then deliver the result of the hexdump (print) to the console.

```
    objdump = "$(objdump -d " + str(_arg_name) + "| grep '^ ' |cut -f2);" + " do echo -n $i; done; echo"
    result = os.popen(objdump).read()
    result = result.replace('"','')
    print(result)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running bash commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Comment: It's not the answer for the my commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
    g1 = "grep '^ '"
    g2 = "cut -f2"

    objdump = "objdump -d " + str(binary) + "|" + g1 + "|" + g2 
    result = os.popen(objdump).read()
    result = result.replace('\n','')
    result = result.replace(' ','')
    length = len(result) - 1
    result = [r'\x' + result[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, length, 2)]
    print(result)
```